# Q: Zyn-fusion doesn't launch, complaining about "/usr/lib/zynaddsubfx/./qml/MainWindow.qml" being missing

Tags: 18.04

Whenever I try to launch zyn-fusion (zynaddsubfx 3.0 and higher) I get this error, in some form.

```
    [INFO] exec-after-init
    [INFO] startup OSC
    [INFO] UI calbacks
    [INFO] OSC replay
    [INFO] auto_save setup
    [INFO] NSM Stuff
    [INFO] LASH Stuff
    [INFO] Launching Zyn-Fusion...
    [INFO] Main Loop...
    [INFO:Zyn] setup_pugl()
    [INFO:Zyn] zest_tick()
    [INFO:Zyn] zest_open()
    [ERROR:Zyn] QML Not Found At "/usr/lib/zynaddsubfx/./qml/MainWindow.qml"...
    [ERROR:Zyn] Zyn Fusion Assets Missing, Please Check Install...
```

I installed zynsubaddfx from the kxstudio repos though a .deb file. I can use and older version of zyn just fine, which hints at it being an issue with the new GUI. any help would be much appreciated, as I'm trying to learn ardour, and that's a little hard without my favorite synth.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I 'solved' it by starting anew with this build :

https://github.com/zynaddsubfx/zyn-fusion-build/wiki/Building-on-Linux

Then in order to get ardour to know about it (because it did not) I noticed it was checking /opt/ardour/lib/LV2 for the plugins. As the folder did not even exist I created a symbolic link :

/opt/ardour/lib/LV2 -> /usr/lib/lv2

And it works just fine.

regards,
MartinMMK

Answer (score 0):

There are two .deb files in kxstudio repositories that you have to install. The first one is the one that matches your Operating System Architecture (`amd64`, `arm64`, `armhf`, `i386`) and the second one is the `data` package.

For example, if you are on an x64 OS, for ZynAddSubFX 3.05 you have to install:

1. zynaddsubfx_3.0.5-1kxstudio5_amd64.deb
2. zynaddsubfx-data_3.0.5-1kxstudio5_all.deb